# Replace function not returning correct values

Tags: python

If I pass 15 (or any 2 digit value) to the following function, I get 00. When I change the "0" in replace to a letter such as "a", I get 1a, 2a, etc...

Why is Python changing the value in 0th and 1st index when I am only specifying the 1st and passing an integer?

```
def BlockCalc(currBlock):
    currBlock = str(currBlock)
    if len(currBlock) == 2:
        currBlock = currBlock.replace(currBlock[1], "0")
        return currBlock
```

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: You aren't specifying a replacement of the first element, you're saying replace every character that is equal to the first element with '0'. So if the first element is '1' all 1s will be replaced with 0. You probably just want to say `curBlock[1] = "0"`.

Comment: @NathanielFord  Well, he could say that if this wasn't a string and therefore immutable...

Comment: @TimRoberts You're correct, of course. Since it's a string object, Igor, it won't behave like you'd expect a mutable array of characters to. Apologies for the misdirect - the point about `replace` stands though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description is wrong.  If you pass 15, the result will be 10.  However, if you pass 11, then you certainly will get 00.  In that case, you are saying "please replace all of the 1s with 0s", and that's exactly what it does.

```
def BlockCalc(currBlock):
    currBlock = str(currBlock)
    if len(currBlock) == 2:
        currBlock = currBlock.replace(currBlock[1], "0")
        return currBlock

print(BlockCalc('11'))
print(BlockCalc('12'))
print(BlockCalc('15'))
```

Output:

```
00
10
10
```

If you really want to replace the second character with '0', that is:

```
    currBlock = currBlock[0] + '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone. I was able to solve my problem quickly.

Answer (score -1):

I would encourage you to read the docs on how the replace function works. It takes 3 arguments.

`string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count?)`

So you're saying, replace all values of currBlock[1] with "0"

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp

Comment: A friendly note, 'I would encourage you to read the docs' comes off very aggressive. Also, it would be helpful to link the actual documentation if you recommend it as the correct course of action: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace